# Detect Audio Output on Mac?

Tags: bash, audio, io, scripting, applescript

Is there a way to detect if audio is being output from the Mac system? Whether it's via headphone jack, usb-c, or bluetooth, is there a process which runs if and only if audio is playing?

I've made a unix script which plays a 15hz sine waveform, the idea is to execute the script every 580 seconds if and only if no audio is playing. If audio is playing, the script won't execute.

I have really good speakers but the drawback is they enter a 'standby' power saver mode every 10 minutes (600 seconds). When I'm at work I don't really care about whether it runs in the background or not* but when I'm at home I tend to miss notifications when speakers enter standby, so the aim of the script is to play the 3 second waveform every 580 seconds if and only if no audio is playing.

Comment: A few things… what version of the OS? Also, your set-up could have whatever audio end two seconds before your test script runs, which would result in your sound being played, even though you're actually 598 seconds from standby mode. Also, could you not just have the sound play each cycle but with the minimum output to fend off standby mode? Finally, in my System Preferences > Accessibility > Audio, there is an option to flash the screen when an alert plays. Maybe that would be helpful.

Comment: Create a wav file containing silence and play it on loop in QuickTime Player or some other app.

Comment: As the average adult human can hear sounds between 20 Hz and 16,000 Hz, why do you want to play at 15 Hz? You must have really good hearing. :)

Comment: MacOS 11.4 and thank you, I will try this solution out. There is no minimum output to fend off standby mode, pretty much any sound output will do, I've kept it at ~3 seconds just to be safe. @Mockman

Comment: That's a bit resource heavy @RhythmicFistman

Comment: lol I wish, but the idea is actually to make it inaudible so as to simply wake the speaker up from standby mode, not actually play anything. @user3439894

Comment: RE: "lol I wish, but the idea is actually to make it inaudible so as to simply wake the speaker up from standby mode, not actually play anything." --  Well that certainly makes sense as log as it will wake the speakers. :)

Comment: @Raj fine, play a short snippet of non-looping silence every `n` minutes: `while :; do afplay sound-of-silence.wav; sleep 579; done`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not necessarily need to use **AppleScript** to accomplish the goal, although you certainly can if you want.

I'd opt to use a **Launch Agent**, as in the following *example* **XML plist** *code*:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>com.my.play.if.no.audio.is.playing</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>/bin/bash</string>
        <string>-c</string>
        <string>[[ $(pmset -g | grep ' sleep') =~ coreaudiod ]] || '/path/to/shell_script'</string>
    </array>
    <key>RunAtLoad</key>
    <false/>
    <key>StartInterval</key>
    <integer>580</integer>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Change `'/path/to/shell_script'` in the **XML plist** *code* to the actual *fully qualified pathname* of your *shell script*.

Then save is as, e.g., `com.my.play.if.no.audio.is.playing.plist` in `~/Library/LaunchAgents/` and load it from **Terminal** using, e.g.:

```
cd ~/Library/LaunchAgents/
launchctl load com.my.play.if.no.audio.is.playing.plist
```

Then every *580 seconds* your *shell script* will execute if there is no audio playing.

---

**Notes:**

As coded, it assumes the *executable bit* is set on your *shell script*.

If you are going to use **Launch Agents** and **Launch Daemons**, I highly recommend you read the *manual pages* for `launchctl`, `launchd.plist` and `launchd`.

You can read the *manual page* for *`command`* in **Terminal** by typing *`man command`*, then press **enter**, or **for easier reading**, just type *`command`* and then right-click on it and select: **Open man Page**

To stop your **Launch Agent**, in **Terminal**:

```
cd ~/Library/LaunchAgents/
launchctl unload com.my.play.if.no.audio.is.playing.plist
```

You could also instead, include the *test condition* in your *shell script*, e.g.:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

if [[ ! $(pmset -g | grep ' sleep') =~ coreaudiod ]]; then

    # Code to generate your sine waveform goes here.

fi
```

Then, the *command* used in the *example* **XML plist** *code* would be:

```xml
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>/path/to/shell_script</string>
    </array>
```

---

If you really want to use **AppleScript**, and assuming a **Stay Open** *application*, then:

*Example* **AppleScript** *code*:

```applescript
on run
    --  # Add any AppleScript code you what run when the
    --  # Stay Open AppleScript application is opened.
    
end run

on idle
    
    do shell script ¬
        "[[ $(pmset -g | grep ' sleep') =~ coreaudiod ]] || '/path/to/shell_script'"
    
    return 580
    
end idle

on quit
    continue quit
end quit
```

---

**Notes:**

When saving the *example* **AppleScript** *code* in **Script Editor** , set **File Format: [Application]** and **[√] Stay open after run handler**.

If your add the *test condition* to your *shell script*, as shown further above, then your `do shell script` *command* would be:

```applescript
do shell script "'/path/to/shell_script'"
```

I tend to stay away from using this type of **AppleScript** *application*, as I find that over time they can/may become resource intensive in that they continue consume more **RAM**.  YMMV.

Comment: Wow this is incredible, thank you so much, I will definitely try to implement the first XML plist since I think that'd be the most computationally efficient and pretty much does exactly what I have in mind. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is super related to what you want but maybe try out [Soundflower](https://soundflower.en.softonic.com/mac/download) ? It's super useful for re-routing audio in mac.